# Google Analytics - Page Views per host

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at Behaviour---> Site Content --> All pages. I can add as a secondary dimension host. Is it possible to group page views by host?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the "Hostname" column by clicking on it. This action would group your pages by the Hostname.